# JS alert in PHP as part of AJAX app

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, alert

I've got a PHP file that is being called to fill in a DIV via ajax. Everything works fine and dandy except I can't for the life of me get a JS alert box to pop up from the PHP.

Here is what I'm using to test (this is being tacked on toward the end of the PHP, I've also tried it toward the beginning, in the middle, etc):

```
 echo "does this show up?";
 echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('thanks!');</script>";
```

"does this show up?" is echoed and I can see the JS in codeinspector but no alert box. If I take that code and throw it in its own PHP file (so it is no longer embedded as part of a larger ajax app) it works just fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you see "<script language='javascript'>alert('thanks!');</script>" in the code inspector or firebug or view source?

Comment: I saw it CodeInspector and Firebug, but I found a work around: I just put it PHP file that contained the DIV tag (that the previous PHP was filling). I don't know why the lower php wasn't working but this workaround is OK for me.

Thanks.

Comment: PHP is never "working" on the client side. that's why. just substitute this PHP file with plain HTML/js file and go experiment with your js. PHP has nothing to do with any client side problems

Answer (score 3):

Sending back a `script` block via AJAX is the **wrong** way to do it. Instead, you should return a value (probably JSON using [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and then decode using the [javascript JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)) and then call alert from your script.

For example, something like this (untested, but you get the idea):

PHP:

```
echo json_encode(Array('OperationSucceeded' => 'true', 'Message' => 'test'));
```

Javascript:

```
retValObj = JSON.parse(retVal);
if (retValObj.Message != null) {
    alert(retValObj.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript is parsed once during  page load. So if u put these code in page it works fine.... Browser does not parse on ajax loaded content...but we can make javascript function calls from ajax loaded content.